# How is Noele's reply related to Craig's question?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, its-kind-of-a-funny-story

In [***Its Kind of a Funny Story***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0804497/), How is Noele reply related to Craig's question?

> Craig: You guys wear uniforms?
>
> Noele: **I Knew it**.

Noele's reply is completely different from the question he asked.

How to understand her reply?

Comment: Huh? It's not an answer, it's related to her *previous* sentence. ["You're not some sort of school uniform perv, are you?" (he asks about the uniform) "...I knew it!" (as in, "you *are* a perv")]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're talking about school uniforms and what she imagines to be an unnatural sexual interest in peope who wear them.

[**Script**](http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~ina22/splaylib/Screenplay-It's_Kind_of_a_Funny_Story.pdf)

> NOELLE: I don’t care too much about school.The teachers think I have a problem
>   with authority. Where do you go?
>
> CRAIG: Executive Pre-Professional. You?
>
> NOELLE : Delfin. You’re not some kind of school uniform perv, are you?
>
> CRAIG: You guys wear uniforms?
>
> NOELLE: See, I knew it!

Basically, she's joking with him in that by **just asking about school uniforms** he is a 'perv'!